# Where is malware stored online before it is downloaded?

Tags: malware

Where can malware be stored online?

I've looked at several websites about malware infection and it mentions things like drive-by downloads and exploit kits, but I can't see where the actual .exe, macro etc files are stored in the first place to be downloaded onto a user's device. Are they placed on servers online and linked to?

Comment: By necessity, anything available for download online would have to be store on some kind of server. Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: That makes sense. Say a Trojan Horse that is downloaded by clicking on a link on a web page, where is the file stored originally? How would it get put there?

Comment: The same way that any file gets put on any webserver.  I don't see your problem here.

Comment: It's usually either hosted on compromised web servers or on servers (e.g. VPSes) rented using stolen credit card information.

Comment: So is this scenario right? A hacker finds their way onto a web server and puts an infected file on it's storage and links to it on a web page. When a user of the site downloads and executes the infected file the bad code runs and does whatever it does, e.g. steals data.